# When would an implementation want to take ownership of self in Rust?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm reading through the Rust documentation on lifetimes. I tried something like:

```
struct S {
    x: i8,
}

impl S {
    fn fun(self) {}

    fn print(&self) {
        println!("{}", self.x);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = S { x: 1 };
    s.fun();
    s.print();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `s`
  --> src/main.rs:16:5
   |
15 |     s.fun();
   |     - value moved here
16 |     s.print();
   |     ^ value borrowed here after move
   |
   = note: move occurs because `s` has type `S`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

This is because the `fun(self)` method takes ownership of the `s` instance. This is solved by changing to `fun(&self)`.

I can't see why you would ever want to have a method on an object take control of itself. I can think of only one example, a destructor method, but if you wanted to do dispose of the object then it would be taken care of by the owner of the object anyway (i.e. scope of `main` in this example).

Why is it possible to write a method that takes ownership of the struct? Is there ever any circumstance where you would want this?

Comment: *I can think of only one example, a destructor method* — Amusingly, [the closest equivalent to a destructor](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) takes the item by mutable reference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The idiomatic way to refer to a method that "takes control" of self in the Rust standard library documentation is to say that it "consumes" it. If you search for this, you should find some examples:

- [`Option::unwrap_or_default`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap_or_default)
- A **lot** in the [`Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) trait.

As to why: you can try rewriting `Iterator::map` — you would end up having a lifetime parameter wandering around that would quickly become unmanageable. Why? Because the `Map` iterator is based upon the previous one, so the borrow checker will enforce that you can only use one of the two at the same time.

Answer (score 6):

Conversion from type A to type B commonly involves functions taking self by value. See the implementors of [`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) and [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) traits for concrete examples.