# When to use self, &self, &mut self in methods?

Tags: rust

What is the difference between a method taking `self` and a method taking `&self` or even `&mut self`?

E.g.

```rust
impl SomeStruct {
    fn example1(self) { }
    fn example2(&self) { }
    fn example3(&mut self) { }
}
```

Say I want to implement a method that pretty prints the struct to stdout, should I take `&self`? I guess `self` also works? I'm not sure when to use what.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the example [in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch05-03-method-syntax.html) (just split onto three separate paragraphs and marked to maybe make it clearer):

> `&self`: We’ve chosen `&self` here for the same reason we used `&Rectangle` in the function version: we don’t want to take ownership, and we just want to read the data in the struct, not write to it.
>
> `&mut self`: If we wanted to change the instance that we’ve called the method on as part of what the method does, we’d use `&mut self` as the first parameter.
>
> `self`: Having a method that takes ownership of the instance by using just `self` as the first parameter is rare; this technique is usually used when the method transforms self into something else and you want to prevent the caller from using the original instance after the transformation.

Or in other words: the difference is exactly the same as `SomeStruct`, `&SomeStruct`, and `&mut SomeStruct`.

> Say I want to implement a method that pretty prints the struct to stdout, should I take `&self`? I guess `self` also works?

As you can see, this is exactly a case for `&self`. If you use `self` (or `&mut self`) the method will likely still compile, but it can only be used in more restricted situations.

Comment: I see. To me it's a bit weird that immutable by reference is not the default here(or actually with any parameter)

Comment: I'm kind of phrasing it wrong; it's not really a default. But the easiest thing to write is just `self`, which is according to the documentation something that is very rare. I would expect things that are rare to be more difficult to write compared to things that are generally used (`&self`).

Comment: Unless the compiler warns when you are passing by value where a reference would be sufficient. I'm kind of scared that I will miss the ampersant in some occasions, making everything a lot less efficient.

Comment: This really applies just as much to non-`self` arguments (as you mention in the beginning).

Comment: Yeah I agree. It's not really part of the question I guess, just something I find weird.

Comment: I've just noticed that I omitted the answer to the last part of your question initially, added it.

Comment: If you forget the ampersand by accident, you will know. The compiler will give you error if you try to use the object after calling such method. Unless the object is `Copy`, in which case passing it by value is cheap anyway.

Comment: @michalsrb But it can potentially be a concern if you provide this method as part of your API, but don't call it yourself (or at least don't call it often enough to run into the problem).

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov If it is part of public API of a library, you should have tests and examples in documentation that use it and so you are likely to discover that problem for yourself.

Comment: I wanna add that [the builder pattern](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/patterns/patterns/creational/builder.html) uses `mut self`, because the return type is `Self`, which doesn't match with `&mut self`.

Answer (score 9):

The other answer is good, but not complete. So, here's more info about `self`, `&self` and `&mut self`.

#### Summary table

|  | Short for | Equivalent to | Takes ownership? | When to use? | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `self` | `self: Self` | `a: A` | Yes | The code that calls this method should not able to reuse the object on which you call the method. | [Invalidate an object because maybe you transform it into another](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html). Drop an object. Immutable data structures? |
| `&self` | `self: &Self` | `a: &A` | No - immutably borrows | For reading `self` or its fields. | For printing something or compute a value based on multiple values of other copyable fields. |
| `&mut self` | `self: &mut Self` | `a: &mut A` | No - mutable borrows | For reading or writing `self` and its fields. | A function that updates the internal state of a data structure. |
| `mut self` | `mut self: Self` | `mut a: A` | Yes | If you want to change what `self` points to. Not useful because it takes ownership. |  |

#### More notes

- `Self` is an alias for the type that the `impl` block is for.
- The rules of ownership and borrowing apply to `self` as they apply to any other parameter (see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29682542/3924118))
- Examples of when to use which [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.self.html) and [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8e8b2263701e827f6965c468a3ef1a6b)
- Examples of when we should take ownership [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36531671/3924118), although the answers don't provide code examples but just point to the docs
- `self` is not just used as the first parameter of a method, but can also be used to reference the current module (more details [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.self.html))
- If you define a variable like this `let foo = Foo::new()` (i.e. you cannot mutate `foo`) and then you attempt to call a method that requires a mutable reference (i.e. the first parameter is `&mut self`), you'll get a compilation error, so you would need to change `let foo` to `let mut foo`. A complete example [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/fn/methods.html)
- More info also [here](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/first-ownership.html)