# unable to compile enum impl methods with values

Tags: rust, methods, enums

This doesn't compile. Why not?

The compiler is happy with the `set_fred()` method, but not with
`get_fred()` and `get_fred_mut()` which reference the same `Fred(String)`.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Unable to compile enum impl methods with values");
}

enum Flintstone {
    Fred(String),
    Wilma(i32),
}

impl Flintstone {
    fn set_fred(&mut self, fred: String) {
        *self = Flintstone::Fred(fred);
    }

    // error[E0609]: no field `Fred` on type `Flintstone`
    fn get_fred(self) -> String {
        self.Fred
    }

    // error[E0609]: no field `Fred` on type `&mut Flintstone`
    fn get_fred_mut(&mut self) -> &mut String {
        &mut self.Fred
    }
}
```

Comment: `enum`s are like a C union.  It doesn't know whether it is Fred or Wilma in those functions.  You might want a `match self`.

Comment: What do you want `get_fred` to do if `self` is a `Flintstone::Wilma(_)`?

Answer (score 0):

They are here a couple of problems.

First is the signature of this method `get_fred(self)` it should be `get_fred(&self)` look at the following example

```
struct Test(i32);

impl Test {
    fn new() -> Self {
        return Self(3);
    }
    
    fn get(self) -> i32 {
        return self.0;
    }
} 

fn main() {
    let t = Test::new();
    
    // Unsurprisingly it prints "The value: 3"
    println!("The value: {}", t.get());
    
    // Because as it is declared self instead of &self in get(self)
    // The ownership is take and t is now doroped
    println!("The value: {}", t.get());
}
```

A fuller explanation here [When to use self, &self, &mut self in methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59018413/when-to-use-self-self-mut-self-in-methods)

Next, the Enum is only in one state. In your case is Flintstone::Fred(String) or Flintstone::Wilma(i32).

So you can deal like this

```
fn get_fred(&self) -> String {
    match self {
        Flintstone::Fred(a) => a.clone(), //<-- Because a is an `&String`
        _ => "".to_string()
    }
}
```

And the mut is not make a lot of sense

```
fn get_fred_mut(&mut self) -> &mut String {
    match self {
        Flintstone::Fred(ref mut a) => a,
        _ => panic!("No fred")
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to return `&str` from `get_fred()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. The intent is to be able to store different types in an enum.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Making progress compiling enum impl methods with values");
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
enum Flintstone {
    Fred(FlintstoneVal),
    Wilma(FlintstoneVal),
    Pebbles(FlintstoneVal),
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
#[allow(non_camel_case_types)]
enum FlintstoneVal {
    fred(i32),
    wilma(String),
    pebbles(bool),
}

#[allow(dead_code)]
impl Flintstone {

    fn set_fred(&mut self, fred: i32) {
        *self = Flintstone::Fred(FlintstoneVal::fred(fred));
    }

    fn get_fred(&self) -> i32 {
        match self {
            Flintstone::Fred(FlintstoneVal::fred(val)) => *val,
            _ => 0_i32,    // This will never match.
        }
    }

    fn set_wilma(&mut self, wilma: String) {
        *self = Flintstone::Wilma(FlintstoneVal::wilma(wilma));
    }
}
```